# How to solve collation conflict in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, collation

I'm getting a "Collation conflict" on SQL server, I'm using the next code and getting that error:

```
with MESF1 as (
SELECT [Error], convert(date,[Now]) as 'Date', COUNT(*) as'Day total', sum([Delta in seconds]) as [Total in seconds]
  FROM [Consolidado-MESF1].[dbo].[MESF1_Data_Summary] A 
  Group by convert(date,[now]), [Error] 
)
 Select a.*, b.[ErrorDescription], (round(((cast(a.[Total in seconds] as numeric )/cast(a.[Day total] as numeric))),3)) 
 as 'Average cycle time' , 
 datepart(wk,a.[date]) as 'WWK',datepart(YYYY,a.[date]) as 'YYYY', datename(DW, a.[date]) as 'Day' from MESF1 a
 inner join [Consolidado-MESF1].[dbo].[MESF1_ERROR_DESCRIPTION] b on a.error = b.ErrorNumber
Union 
   Select a.*, b.[Item Type Description], (round(((cast(a.[Total in seconds] as numeric )/cast(a.[Day total] as numeric))),3)) 
   as 'Average cycle time' , 
 datepart(wk,a.[date]) as 'WWK',datepart(YYYY,a.[date]) as 'YYYY', datename(DW, a.[date]) as 'Day' from MESF1 a
 inner join [ProductList].[dbo].[Prodinfo] b on a.error = b.[FG OPC] collate SQL_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as
--date period YYYY-MM-DD
--where [date] between '2020-06-06' and '2020-08-06'
  order by a.[Date] asc;
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
End
```

The error shown is:

> Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 103
> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Modern_Spanish_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

I already tried changing in the design menu from Windows collation to SQL collation and the next query:

```
ALTER table [dbo].[MESF1_ERROR_DESCRIPTION]
ALTER COLUMN [ErrorDescription]
VARCHAR(max) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL
```

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: What about the other join columns, what are their collations? Go through all the columns, you have a mismatch somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Use

COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT

instead of

collate SQL_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as